# Loop until no errors

Tags: programming, warning-messages

I am doing some numeric computations, involving `FindMinimum` and `FindDistributionParameters`. I think these functions have some stochastic element because the answers I get on identical input sometimes are different. In rare occasions, I get an error message indicating no convergence. If this happens, I would like to repeat the calculation from the start, and repeat until convergence.  If possible, I do not want to generate any messages, since in the end I am sure it will converge.

So I am looking for a wrapper of the form:

```
wrap[computation[]]
```

where `computation[]` is a complicated function involving `FindMinimum` and `FindDistributionParameters` that might generate messages. If messages are generated, I want `wrap` to detect these messages, not print them, and simply attempt to execute `computation[]` again. Repeat this until `computation[]` does not generate messages, and simply return the output of `computation[]`.

**Update:** Sometimes `computation[]` seems to get stuck, taking a very long time. Is it possible to add a second argument to `wrap[..., time]`, so that if `computation[]` takes longer than `time` to complete, it aborts, and starts running `computation[]` again?

Comment: Check ? http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Check.html
i think you can  use Catch and Throw to exit a loop when a value shows up

Comment: check also: [TimeConstrained](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TimeConstrained.html) and [$MessageList](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$MessageList.html)

Comment: @kglr But how can I keep the loop going, until no messages are generated?

Comment: becko, `While[$MessageList =!= {}, computation[]]`?

Comment: Check[computation[],computation[] ]  ?

Comment: @Alucard What if `computation[]` generates messages twice?

Comment: @kglr That will print messages to the screen if they are generated, right?

Comment: @becko i didn't think about this case. do this code make sense to you? i am not sure
 fun3 := Check[computation[], Abort[]]
fun4 := CheckAbort[fun3, fun4]
fun4

Comment: becko, yes. You can use `Quiet@While[...]` to suppress printing.

Comment: @kglr Thanks, that almost works. What about the time constraint? Note that TimeConstrained simply stops the computation. I want the computation to restart if it takes too long.

Comment: becko, use the three-argument form: `TimeConstrained[expr, time, expr]`

Comment: @kglr I don't think that will loop. I want an infinite loop, where each time the computation exceeds the time constraint, it tries again, until a result is obtained without errors and under the time constraint.

Comment: becko, does this give what you need: `Quiet@While[$MessageList =!= {} || tc === $Aborted, 
  tc = TimeConstrained[computation[], time]]`?

Comment: @kglr `While[$MessageList =!= {} ...` will not even start, because `$MessageList` is initially empty.

Comment: @kglr I added a variable, initially set to True, that I set to False inside the While. It works, but there should be a cleaner way.

Comment: @becko, not much cleaner, but maybe `Quiet@While[ml =!= {} || tc =!= $Aborted, 
  tc = TimeConstrained[computation[]; ml = $MessageList, time]]`

Comment: @kglr Thanks. You can post an answer if you want.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to repeat evaluation of some expression until no messages have been generated (possibly indefinitely) you can use `Check` recursively.

```
SetAttributes[repeatOnMessage, HoldAll];
repeatOnMessage[expr_] := Quiet@Check[expr, repeatOnMessage[expr]]
```

Let's define a test function that issues a message (and takes some time doing so) most of the time.

```
f::msg = "some message has been issued.";
f[] := If[RandomReal[] > 0.1, (Pause[1]; Message[f::msg]), "result"]
```

Now the following loops until a result is returned (possibly indefinitely if `f` were to never return without a message):

```
repeatOnMessage[f[]]
```

To address your second question you can use `TimeConstrained` inside `repeatOnMessage` as in

```
failed::msg = "Computation has been aborted";
repeatOnMessage[TimeConstrained[f[], 0.5, Message[failed::msg]]]
```

Note that using the third argument of `TimeConstrained` is needed to issue a message, otherwise `TimeConstrained` returns `$Aborted` which is not caught by `Check` inside `repeatOnMessage`.

In a real setting it would probably be wise to use `TimeConstrained` on the call of `repeatOnMessage` itself, to not have it recurse indefinitely if the expression does never return without a message.

```
TimeConstrained[repeatOnMessage[TimeConstrained[f[], 0.5, Message[failed::msg]]], 4]
```

Using this scheme allows you to

1. specify how long each inner call may take to reach a result before retrying
2. specify how long the expression should be reevaluated before giving up completely (and what to do in this case)

Comment: I think that `repeatOnMessage[TimeConstrained[f[], 0.5, Message[failed::msg]]]` will repeat the calculation whenever `f[]` takes less than 0.5 seconds to complete. This is the *opposite* of what I want.

Comment: @becko `repeatOnMessage[expr]` repeats evaluating `expr` whenever a message is issues from within `expr`. That is all it does. `TimeConstrained[f[], 0.5, Message[failed::msg]]` does evaluate `f[]` and issues a message if the time constrained is reached. `repeatOnMessage` then kicks in and tries evaluating `TimeConstrained[f[], 0.5, Message[failed::msg]]` again.

Comment: Actually, `TimeConstrained[f[], 0.5, Message[failed::msg]]` issues a message if the time constraint *is not met*. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeConstrained.html.

Comment: Isn't this what you want? Evaluation is aborted by `TimeConstrained` if it takes longer than `0.5`s and the result returned if a result is found in time.  Try `TimeConstrained[(Pause[1]; 
  "finished in time!"), 0.5, "not finished in time!"]` to see what is returned when.